# Can we have Tree Grid in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

can we have the tree grid : [Link to tree grid in GXT](http://examples.sencha.com/gxt/4.0.0/#ExamplePlace:basictreegrid) in GWT pure ?
If not can I create the same component ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with pure GWT. There is a very simple example in the GWT showcase page: http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid

in this case the "show friends" should be replaced by a "+" button or something similiar to the gxt.
basically you have to extends the `AbstractCellTableBuilder` and user it with your daragrid: `grid.setTableBuilder(tableBuilder);`
another basic example you can find [here](https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-celltable-subrows), its not a generic solution, but it works.

i've used subrows in a datagrid before, and its okay, but as soon you want editable subrows you will get problems...

Comment: Yes, I saw this things but I don't know if I can do something like this : [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/155338Sanstitre.png). Can I ?

Comment: thats what i was referring to. you have to replace the "show friends" text with some image or whatever you like. ive created a generic subrowdecorator before, so yes, you can do it. anyway it works only with one level of subrows and you cant use editable rows...

Comment: I express myself wrong, I wanted to know the number of level I can create. Your solution only have one but I can have severals with another implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in vanilla GWT.
Yes you can create it (since GXT is created with GWT....)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think it's hard to create ? I think I need to use `DataGrid` and `CellTree` no ?

Comment: I think only a DataGrid. But I don't use the GWT widgets. I use GwtBootstrap3 with a lot of custom made Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it's a bit time consuming. I have been there. I advise you to use GXT. here is an example from my github: https://github.com/zak905/treegridgxt